# Insert a variable from a python script into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I'm relatively new into Python and I've got a question: How can I input a variable into an SQL execution?

```
sql = "Insert INTO links VALUES('stackoverflow')"
```

Obviously, 'stackoverflow' is just a string but what do I need to change if I want to **insert a variable**?

Thanks for your help!
Melodlebron

Answer (score -2, accepted):

what you seem to be needing is a dynamically formatted string, Python has those in the form of:

```
 stackoverflowString = "stackoverflow"
 sql = ("Insert INTO links VALUES('%s')" % stackoverflowString)
```

This will replace the string `stackoverflowString` inside the SQL statement.

Comment: What happens if `stackoverflowString` is `'DROP TABLE links;--` in your case? (hint: nothing good). The query needs to be properly parametrized.

Comment: Thank you I forgot to escape the string.

Comment: The brackets around the query don't make it any safer.

Comment: Just leave parametrizing to the sql-connector you are using. `cursor.execute(insert_statement, data)` will work perfectly fine, no reason to homebrew these things.

Comment: Thanks it worked! You're great!

Comment: But please, @Melodlebron, if you are using the cursor.execute please follow what Christian W. said because it is much safer. This also dependes if that dynamic parameter is accessible through user input or a source that you do not control.